# Explain a conceptual relationship between PMF and RV?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, random-variable

I'm new to this topic and am a little confused about exactly how the two terms are related.

What I understand as of now is that:

RV -> function that maps a random process a value

PMF -> Probability that your random variable takes on some value k and then spits out its mass over that value.

My questions are:

1) I'm not sure how to visualize this concept.
2) Does Mass in PMF refer to the number of times the RV gets a particular value?

3) How would you explain this for example for a fair dice roll, where RV is defined as the factorial of the number rolled? what would the PMF look like?

Note: RV= Random Variable
PMF = Probability Mass Function

Comment: Please start by reviewing the definitions.  Here's a set of links: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=random+variable+sample+space.

Answer (score 0):

A random variable doesn't map a random process to a value; it maps an element in the sample space to a value. To be precise, a random variable is a real-valued function of a measure space that's measureable (i.e., the preimage of any Borel set under the function is measurable).

A PMF (which only exists for discrete random variables) for a random variable $X$ is just a function $f : ℝ → ℝ$ such that for any real $x$, $f(x)$ is the probability that $X = x$.

> How would you explain this for example for a fair dice roll, where RV is defined as the factorial of the number rolled? what would the PMF look like?

It would be defined by $f(x) = \frac{1}{6}$ for $x ∈ \{1!, 2!, 3!, 4!, 5!, 6!\}$ and $f(x) = 0$ for all other $x$.